# Cannot resolve by hostname only in other local namespace

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, internal-dns

We have three local namespaces: proddomain.local, testdomain.local, devdomain.local. All of our client computers in the organization are part of the proddomain.local domain. If I select "Disable NetBIOS over TCP/IP" on the WINS tab of the Advanced TCP/IP Settings dialog (Windows 7) and "ping devcomp1" I get back "Ping request could not find host devcomp1." (If I leave the NetBIOS setting on Default and ping devcomp1 I get back, "Pinging devcomp1" with the IP address, etc.) On Wireshark I see the response from the DNS server as "No such name". I am, however, able to sucessfully ping devcomp1.devdomain.local.

I'm researching how the DNS could be misconfigured but I wanted to put this out there as part of my investigation.

Comment: ...and your question would be...?

Comment: Yeah, I left out the question. My question is, "What, specifically, should I be looking at to resolve this?" Or could it be lots of things?

Comment: DNS isn't missing anything. It can't resolve unqualified names. How would it know what zone to query for an unqualified name? What if you had 1,000 zones? Do you want it to query each zone for devcomp1? What if you had a matching record for devcomp1 in 50 of those zones? Which one do you want it to return? My point is, you need to submit a fully qualified query to DNS in order to get an answer. Now you could deploy a GlobalNames zone, but that doesn't seem to fit here and isn't really an answer to your question. - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731744.aspx

Comment: This makes sense to me. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely missing the **Append these DNS suffixes** configuration in the DNS tab of the advanced setting dialog.

This will make sure that the three domains will be appended (in order) when trying to resolve unqualified names.

Comment: I found that if I filled in the **Append these DNS suffixes** box it will resolve the IP address of the hostname. But then I'd have to set that for all of my clients. Isn't there a way to have this work on the server?

Comment: You can do this on the [DHCP server](http://msmvps.com/blogs/acefekay/archive/2011/02/12/configuring-dns-search-suffixes.aspx). Not the DNS server.

Comment: @kleefaj Typically, you'd use a GPO to assign these settings to all your clients... or, yeah, the DHCP server, provided all your clients get addresses from DHCP.